# Angular Dependencies Between Modules

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, module, bootstrapping

I'm facing a problem using Dependency Injection between modules.
I have a module that implements a directive I need to use in other applications.

I added the dependency from this module in another app declaration like this:

```
angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute', 'directiveApp']);
```

However, the methods implemented into directiveApp.controller, doesn't seem to be visible from a page of MainApp, since the directive can't run a method it needs from their controller.

I know it's a little confusing, so I put an example in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LXSggfavpBDfhuAOKalb?p=preview), that shows the problem I'm facing.

Comment: You do not reference `SubCtrl` in the template.  So, no `ng-click` method will bind.

Comment: To clarify on the above comment, including modules does not make everything automatically available anywhere. All you are doing is just making the controller available. So you still need to include that controller in something, either via view or route.

Comment: As I mentioned, the subModule is about a directive. Do you thing I can force the controller inside that directive (maybe using the controller property of the configuration object for my directive), instead of embed the directive inside a ng-controller? I'm just wondering if I can make the use of this directive more easy to add in other applications. What happens is the directive is a common UI object in a lot of apps in my organization. I'm trying to turn it into a component I can easily add and use in any of those apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you inject another module into your own, the controllers and directives it implements become available, but you need to use them properly.

The way you are trying to do is not possible, you can do something like this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/peHH226vxtkI48RFZ3Eq?p=preview

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Value: {{name}}!</h1>
    <button ng-click="mainModule()">Call a function in the main module!</button>

    <div ng-controller="SubCtrl">
      {{name}}
      <button ng-click="dependentModule()">Call a function in the dependent module!</button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

But notice that you have two different `$scopes` and consequently two different `name` variables.

That means your `dependentModule()` function belongs to your `SubCtrl` and you can only use it inside its own `$scope`

---

That's not recommended, but if you really need to, you can use the other controllers on your own methods and then copy the results:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ranK9n08NNVuSKIGX15G?p=preview

```
main.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $controller) {


  $scope.name = "Initial value";
  $scope.mainModule = function() {
    $scope.name = "a function in the same module";
  };

  $scope.bridgeFunction = function(){
    // Create a new scope
    var injectedScope = $scope.$new();

    // Use it on the other controller
    $controller('SubCtrl',{$scope : injectedScope });

    // Call the methdo on the controller
    testCtrl1ViewModel.dependentModule(); //And call the method on the newScope.

    // Copy the result from that scope into your own
    $scope.name = testCtrl1ViewModel.name;
  }

});
```

---

A third option is to merge the two scopes, although this can get very messy, it is possible:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1NKStMuYy0e00dhuWKUD?p=preview

```
main.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $controller) {

  $scope.name = "Initial value";

  //This can get very messy, but it is possible to merge the two scopes:
  $controller('SubCtrl',{$scope : $scope });

  $scope.mainModule = function() {
    $scope.name = "a function in the same module";
  };

});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks man... the first option worked great for me, although it seems odd I can reference the controller of the DirectiveApp since I didn't declare the app via ng-app or bootstrap. I can only assume that the dependency injection has made available the controller within the MainApp. Is something like that?